# Track library hosted on github within my own local repository?

Tags: git, version-control, github

I have a project that I'm using git locally to manage my source code. There is an open source library on github that I want to use in my app, but I want to make sure that if there are changes on the public github repository I can easily integrate them with my code. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use a git submodule.  It allows you to track the remote but also allows you to bind versions of your code to versions of the remote.  They aren't trivial to use so read up a bit on git submodule {add,init,update}